# form action=" " HTML what is the action code to process the form?

Tags: html, asp.net

I haven't found a specific "form action=" " code to process the html form.

I am looking for the Google form action code that will process the form as an email. The email instructions are shown in the first two "input type" lines of code. Also a redirect to a "thank you" page is shown in the last "input type" line of code.

This form was used for recaptcha V1 for a long time using a captcha v1 action without a problem.

The form is at http://www.datatronics.com/form-sample-request.asp. When I submit the form it should send a email with the answers to the sample request form to the email address at www.datatronics.com

What is the missing action value for the "sample-request?

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>

<form action="  " method="POST">

<input type="hidden" name="mailfrom" value="www@www.datatronics.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="mailto" value="xxxxx@gmail.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Sample Request" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirecturl" value="/thankyou.htm" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not a missing action code. It means form is submitted at server to the same page address. `action=""` resolves to current page address, and `action="?"` or `action="#"` resolves to current page address with `?` or `#` as suffixed respectively or any other given symbol. 
You will see this type in lot of old developments until HTML5 came in and then `action` attribute became optional.

Check this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) stating:

> Many older pages use the following notation to indicate that the data should be sent to the same page that contains the form; this was required because until HTML5, the action attribute was required. This is no longer needed.

Comment: I want the action to send an email to Datatronics with the info from the completed form, not revert back to the original Datatronics site.

Comment: So you are using a google form ? If yes, then your action code should be a url pointing to your google form ID. Something like below:
`https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/@formid/formResponse?embedded=true`. If that's not the case, please clarify your question further what you need.

Comment: Did it help you ?

Comment: I am using a HTML form and with the reCAPTCHA I am using Google for the processing. With reCaptcha V1 I just use the input for the form action to process the form